# Oracle Pivot over Sequence of values

Tags: oracle11g, pivot, pivot-table, sequence

I need to pivot a table over a column that can take a hundred values, so I would prefer to define the range of possible values succinctly rather than typing out each one. It seems the `SEQUENCE` object should allow me to specify this range, but I'm struggling to incorporate it into the `PIVOT` syntax.

Secondly, I would like to set the resulting pivotted columns conditional on another column.

What I've tried so far:

```
SELECT * FROM table
PIVOT
(
  COUNT(effect)
  FOR column
  IN VALUES(CREATE SEQUENCE my_seq
            INCREMENT BY 1
            START WITH 1
            MAXVALUE 100)
)
```

My input table looks something like this, where each user has up to 3 values of `feature` with a corresponding `effect` that increases (`incr`) or decreases (`decr`):

```
user   column   effect
a      1        incr
a      5        decr
a      100      decr
b      1        decr
b      20       decr
b      40       decr
c      1        decr
c      5        incr
c      20       incr
```

My desired output should have a +1/-1 when a column has an increasing/decreasing effect and NULL otherwise:

```
user   column_1   column_5 ... column_20 ...
a      1          -1           NULL   
b      -1         NULL         -1
c      -1         1            1
```

--

Edit:
I realise that `COUNT()` won't set the columns to +1/-1/NULL, but I'm just trying to settle the `SEQUENCE` issue first. Perhaps I should just be using a very long-winded set of `CASE` statements followed by a `PARTITION` to collapse them all to one line per user (see below)?

```
WITH effects AS
(
SELECT
    user,
    CASE WHEN column = 1 THEN 
        CASE WHEN effect = 'incr' THEN 1
             WHEN effect = 'decr' THEN -1
             ELSE NULL
             END
        ELSE NULL
    END AS column_1
FROM
    table
)
SELECT
    user,
    MAX(column_1) OVER (PARTITION BY user) AS column_1
FROM
    effects
```

Answer (score 1):

A sequence is a permanent database object, you can't define one on the fly like that; and even with a sequence you would have use `nextval` to get the values.

Oracle has to know how many columns the query will produce when it is parsed, so you can't have a number of columns decided at runtime, which is what you are attempting. If you really don't know then you have to use dynamic SQL; or an XML pivot, which you then have to unpack. [From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#CHDFAFIE):

> The XML keyword permits the pivot_in_clause to contain either a subquery or the wildcard keyword ANY. Subqueries and ANY wildcards are useful when the pivot_in_clause values are not known in advance.

In this case it would be simpler to generate the statement - saving you typing all the values - with another query. You can get the numbers 1-100 with a hierarchical query or recursive CTE, and can then use `listagg()` to form them into a list of values:

```
with t (n) as (
  select 1 from dual
  union all
  select n + 1 from t where n < 100
)
select listagg(n, ', ') within group (order by n)
from t;

LISTAGG(N,',')WITHINGROUP(ORDERBYN)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100
```

You can then use that as part of a string that forms the whole query:

```
with t (n) as (
  select 1 from dual
  union all
  select n + 1 from t where n < 100
)
select q'^select *
from your_table
pivot (
  max(case effect when 'incr' then 1 when 'decr' then -1 end)
  for col in (^' || listagg(n, ', ') within group (order by n) || q'^)
)
order by usr^'
from t;

Q'^SELECT*FROMYOUR_TABLEPIVOT(MAX(CASEEFFECTWHEN'INCR'THEN1WHEN'DECR'THEN-1END)FORCOLIN(^'||LISTAGG(N,',')WITHINGROUP(ORDERBYN)||Q'^))ORDERBYUSR^'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
select *
from your_table
pivot (
  max(case effect when 'incr' then 1 when 'decr' then -1 end)
  for col in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100)
)
order by usr
```

And then run the generated statement:

```
select *
from your_table
pivot (
  max(case effect when 'incr' then 1 when 'decr' then -1 end)
  for col in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100)
)
order by usr;

U          1          2          3          4          5          6          7          8          9         10         11         12         13         14         15         16         17         18         19         20         21         22         23         24         25         26         27         28         29         30         31         32         33         34         35         36         37         38         39         40         41         42         43         44         45         46         47         48         49         50         51         52         53         54         55         56         57         58         59         60         61         62         63         64         65         66         67         68         69         70         71         72         73         74         75         76         77         78         79         80         81         82         83         84         85         86         87         88         89         90         91         92         93         94         95         96         97         98         99        100
- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
a          1                                          -1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   -1
b         -1                                                                                                                                                                                                               -1                                                                                                                                                                                                                          -1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
c         -1                                           1                                                                                                                                                                    1
```

You could run the generated statement as dynamic SQL of course, but copy and paste is simpler if you can do that.

---

You could also vary this to make the CTE only pull out values that actually exist in the table:

```
t (n) as (
  select distinct col from your_table
)
select q'^select *
from your_table
pivot (
  max(case effect when 'incr' then 1 when 'decr' then -1 end)
  for col in (^' || listagg(n, ', ') within group (order by n) || q'^)
)
order by usr^'
from t;
```

which generates:

```
select *
from your_table
pivot (
  max(case effect when 'incr' then 1 when 'decr' then -1 end)
  for col in (1, 5, 20, 40, 100)
)
order by usr
```

which when run then gives the more manageable final result:

```
U          1          5         20         40        100
- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
a          1         -1                               -1
b         -1                    -1         -1           
c         -1          1          1
```